# Objective C + how to create a new thread and post messages to it

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am having trouble creating a new thread in Objective C

```
- (void) create
{
     NSLog( @"Hello World from create \n" );
     NSThread* evtThread = [ [NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                            selector:@selector( saySomething )
                          object:nil ];

    [ evtThread start ];
}

 - (void) saySomething
 {
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    printf( "Hello world from new thread \n");
    NSLog( @"Hello World from new thread \n" );
    //[pool release]; 
 }
```

But it looks like the method saySomething is not being called. Nothing gets printed in the console.

Comment: Are you sure?  Set a breakpoint on the call to NSLog.  You'll know if it getting called, and on which thread.

Comment: I did like you suggested. I put the breakpoint on NSLog but it doesnt hit the breakpoint at all.

Comment: Have a look at the answer by @zoul

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure you want explicit thread control? Most probably you don’t. How about GCD?

```
- (void) create
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self saySomething];
    });
}
```

As for your problem, if you use ARC, the thread will probably get released right after you return from `create`, so that it doesn’t get a chance to perform the selector. You’d have to store the thread into a `strong` instance variable or something like that.

Comment: Wouldn't dispatching to the main queue be more appropriate for calling NSLog?

Comment: With `NSLog` there’s little difference. I was assuming he wants to do something that takes longer, otherwise there would be little point in creating an extra thread.

Comment: I have no idead what a GCD is. I am new to Objective C. I am trying to  use threading as a workaround for an issue that I am having.

Comment: GCD means [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), it’s a technology that greatly simplifies multithreaded programming. The sample code I gave in the answer should work as it is, and I think it’s a good idea to peek at the docs. Otherwise, using an extra thread to get around some code issues is like using a chainsaw to wipe your nose.

Comment: @Zoul. Thanks but it looks like GCD is available only from 10.6 OS X. I need something that will work on earlier versions of Mac.

Comment: 10.6 was released three years ago, but if you insist on supporting older OS X version (or can't affect the decision), `performSelectorInBackground` should still be easier than running the thread by hand. If it's available on 10.5, that is.

Answer (score 8):

Try starting a thread this way:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saySomething) withObject:nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void) create
{
     NSLog( @"Hello World from create \n" );
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saySomething) withObject:nil];
}


- (void) saySomething
 {
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    printf( "Hello world from new thread \n");
    NSLog( @"Hello World from new thread \n" );
    //[pool release]; 
 }
```

Comment: That didnt really help

- (void) create
{
 NSLog( @"Hello World from create \n" );
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saySomething) withObject:nil];
 [pool release];
}

- (void) saySomething
{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 printf( "Hello world from new thread1. \n");
 NSLog( @"Hello World from new thread \n" );
 [pool release];
}
@end

The reason I added the NSAutoreleasePool around the new thread is cause it compained about NSAutoreleasePool not being in place.

Comment: Give four space in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your responses. This might have been a false alarm. Apart from all the mistakes in the code, I think the sample itself was not correct. Immediately after the 'create method' the application exits, so it didnt have any time to printout the stuff from the new thread.

Here is what I did. I copied the code from this link

http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.cocoa.php

and it worked fine. As soon as I removed the 'for loops' and put in just print statements, there was no output from the new thread. So I added in a sleep and now I see the messages from the new thread. Here is the new code.

```
- (void) create
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(aMethod:) toTarget:[Activ class]     
    withObject:nil];
    NSLog( @"Hello from create. \n" ); 
    sleep(1);
    [pool release]; 
}

+(void)aMethod:(id)param
{
    NSLog( @"Hello from new thread. \n" );
}
```

This gives me the following ouput.

```
Running…
2012-07-24 11:21:32.769 [2065:20f] Hello from new thread. 
2012-07-24 11:21:32.769 [2065:a0f] Hello from create. 

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

If I comment out the sleep then I get the following output.

```
Running…
2012-07-24 11:21:23.080 [2038:a0f] Hello from create. 

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be super useful if you could rewrite this answer so that readers can produce the output that you show. For instance, I see no main() in this. As well, to prove it's really a new thread, it would be useful if you could show two new thread connections and return some kind of unique ID for each so that you prove that each thread is running independently.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using dispatch_async() or performSelectorInBackground are probably what you want. However, to the point of why doesn't your code produce any output, the method signature should  have one and only one argument. Change the method to

```
-(void) saySomething:(id)foo;
```

and change the selector to

```
selector:@selector(saySomething:)
```

"The selector for the message to send to target. This selector must take only one argument and must not have a return value." -[NSThread Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/initWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a)

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by saying the method signature should have one and only one argument. I thought I wasn't passing in any argument.

Comment: -(void) saySomething; has no arguments,   -(void)saySomething:(id)foo; has one argument. One and only one argument is required by NSThread.

Answer (score -1):

Please try in following manner.

```
- (void) create
{
     NSLog( @"Hello World from create \n" );

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(saySomething) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}

 - (void) saySomething
 {

    printf( "Hello world from new thread \n");
    NSLog( @"Hello World from new thread \n" );

 }
```